# Track user clicks from list populated of URL's using MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC 5 application that displays a list of 100+ unique URL's. The user can sort, search, and eventually click the URL from the list launching the website in a new window. I want to be able to track every time someone clicks a URL from that list. The URL list is populating as expected. View code below:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1">
                @Html.ActionLink(" Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ReportNameSortParam, SelectedReportCategory = ViewBag.SelectedReportCategory, FindReportName = ViewBag.FindReportName}, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-sort", @title = "sort by name" })
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (ViewBag.counter == "")
            {
                ViewBag.rowType = "normalRow";
                ViewBag.counter = "1";
            }
            else {
                ViewBag.rowType = "alternateRow";
                ViewBag.counter = "";
            }
            <tr class=@ViewBag.rowType>
                <td class="col-md-1" title="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Report_Description) : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SLA)">
                    <a href='@item.Report_Link' target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Report_Name)</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

</table>
```

What would be the best approach to track a user click when they are doing this via the View? I have a column in my table called 'Hits' that I would like to increment by 1 whenever that URL gets clicked. Ideally, after a user clicks a URL, I would like for the list to stay where it is and not have to refresh by hitting another controller and then repopulating. How can I write to the database on via the View?

Comment: Perform an Ajax post when the link is clicked

Comment: I agree with @Wheels73, this work is for Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned... capture the click event of each link clicked and perform an Ajax post to the relevant controller and action.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        var linkID = $(this).attr("id");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")",
                data:
                {
                    linkid: linkID
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Wheels73 for the post. One question I have for you. When the Ajax function "POSTS", will my URL list have to reload OR will the the Ajax post do everything behind the scenes not causing me to reload the list?

Comment: @GRU119 - No.. your list will remain in tact. That's the beauty of Ajax. One of it's main functions is to allow posts to be made without having to update the current view.. or in some cases allows you to update partial views contained within the main view without the whole page refreshing.

Comment: I used your example and it worked like a charm! You are the man @Wheels73! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider standing up an action method that receives the URL and redirects to the final destination:

```
<a href='Redirect?id=@item.ID&url=@item.Report_Link' target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Report_Name)</a>
```

In the controller, add:

```
public ActionResult Redirect(int id, string url)
{
   //Get record using ID, and update Hits column

   //Redirect to the final URL
   return Redirect(url);
}
```

Be aware that if your URL's use any special characters, some encoding may occur... that might mean you have to do some encoding on the client end potentially.  It's just good to test that out to confirm.

Comment: thank you for your post. I'm going to try to go the Ajax route. I will be sure to post my answer if I can get this working. I appreciate your response.